# Import a .pbix file to Pbi Service using API REST from Storage Account

Tags: powershell, rest, powerbi, request

I want to publish a .pbix that I have In a Storage Account into the pbi service But I keep getting Bad Request. I've tried Powershell and the sandbox from Microsoft Learn. I'm trying to call to this endpoint POST [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/imports?datasetDisplayName={datasetDisplayName}](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/%7BgroupId%7D/imports?datasetDisplayName=%7BdatasetDisplayName%7D)

[image: Microsoft Learning API Call]

All the ways I've seen on how to do this involve a local file, which works fine, "D:\File.exe", for example If I use Postman It works fine

[image: Postman successfully call because the file is on Form-Data format]

but I don't want to involve my local machine.

I want this:

Blob Storage -----> PowerBi Service. (I'm planning to run the script in ADF)

I believe the problem is on how do I send the file(OR SAS URL) to the API as a form data (Already try ContentType="multipart/form-data" as my headers) in the body of my request. The Doc says:

"To import a file, specify the content type multipart/form-data in the request headers and encode the file as form data in the request body"

This is the documentation that I've been working:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/imports/post-import-in-group#code-try-0

I've also tried this code too:
https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/blob/master/PowerShell%20Scripts/Import%20Large%20Files